# Poisson integral on $\mathbb{D}$ is surjective

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, harmonic-functions

If $\phi:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$ is a homeomorphism then its harmonic extension on $\mathbb{D}$ is given by,
$$ f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{it}-z|^2}\phi(e^{it}) .$$

I was able to prove the following things:

1. $f$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{D}$ and is continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}.$
2. $f$ is locally univalent (one-to-one)

I tried to show the surjectivity, by saying that if it is not surjective, then let $f$ misses at least one point, say $w$ from co-domain $\mathbb{D}$. Now since $f$ is continuous and hence will miss a ball around $w$ (the main thing is that the ball may be open entirely in the interior or may be open in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. After that, I am unable to get a contradiction.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any continuous map $g:\overline{\mathbb{D}}\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ such that $g(\theta)=\theta$ for all $\theta\in\mathbb{S}^1$ will necessarily be surjective. If it weren't, you could construct a retract from $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ to $\mathbb{S}^1$. I specifically have in mind $g=h\circ f$ where $h$ is the extension of $\phi^{-1}$. And a surjective composition has one of the factors being surjective (forget which... might have to switch $h$ and $f$).

Comment: First of all, why such an extension exist (because the proof that  I am doing is for the existence of extensions of diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{S}^1$)?

Comment: What you wrote is not the Poisson indegral! If you really mean Poisson integral, please correct.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, yeah I have edited my question. Basically, in the denominator, it will be $ |e^{it}-z|^2 $.  A  mapping from $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is harmonic if both the real and complex part is harmonic.

Comment: Isn't this Rado-Knesser-Choquet?

Comment: argument principle for sense preserving harmonic functions (which $f$ is assuming $\phi$ is, otherwise conjugate)

Comment: @Conrad, but the argument principle will only ensure the injectivity, not the surjectivity.

Comment: why? if $w$ is not in $f(S^1)$, $f-w$ is not zero on $S^1$ so the winding number of $f-w$ is the same as the one of $f$ so it's non-zero - this works for f continuous functions in the unit disc (not necessarily harmonic or analytic), the problem is that indexes of zeros are positive for sense preserving harmonic functions or analytic ones but not necessarily in general; also zeros may not be discrete

Comment: non-zero of course if $|w|<1$ (and zero if $|w|>1$ by the usual interior/exterior stuff for Jordan curves)

Comment: Rouche theorem (argument principle) holds for all open discrete maps.

Comment: @Conrad, sorry but I didn't get your argument. Suppose $w$ is not int image. So, $w\in \operatorname{int} \Omega$. So, the winding number of $f-w$ is the same as the winding number of $f$. After that how are you claiming that $f-w$ has a zero>

Comment: the winding number of $f$ is $\pm 1$ since $f$ is a homeomorphism on the boundary ($+$ if it preserves orientation)

Comment: @Conrad, This is precisely what I am unable to do, the winding number of $f$ is ±1 since $f$ is a homeomorphism on the boundary. Is it true for any Jordan curve?

Comment: Yes by the Jordan curve theorem

Comment: Okay, thanks. This makes sense.